# how to generate linear X Y data to regression practice in Python

Tags: python, numpy, linear-regression

Que: how can i get linear relation between each features/independent variables (X) and target (Y). Both X and Y must be real-values.

But my plot shows only 1/10 features is linearly associated with my target.

Pls see code to generate data with true coefficients to test linear regression with SGD
i found that scatter of each feature vrs target may not be linearly correlated

```
import numpy as np

##generate data
np.random.seed(0)  # for reproducibility
def rand_X_y_LR(nsamples=None, nfeatures=None, plot_XY = False):

        # Define the number of samples and features
        num_samples = nsamples
        num_features = nfeatures

        # Generate a random design matrix X with values between 0 and 1
        X = np.random.rand(num_samples, num_features)
        print(f"shape of random X; {X.shape}")
        ones_column = np.ones((len(X), 1))
        print(f"shape ones_column, {ones_column.shape}")
        X_plusOnes=np.hstack([ones_column, X])
        print(f"shape of X_plusOnes_column, {X_plusOnes.shape}")

        # Generate random coefficients for the features
        true_coefficients = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1, size=(num_features+1))
        print(f"shape of true_coefficients; {true_coefficients.shape}")

        # Generate random noise for the target variable
        noise = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1)

        # Calculate the target variable y using a linear combination of X and coefficients
        #y = np.dot(X_plusOnes, true_coefficients) + noise #X dot B
        y =  X_plusOnes @ true_coefficients + noise #X@B
        print(f"y.shape; {y.shape}")

        if plot_XY == True:
            #plot each X column against target
            fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=round(num_features/2), ncols=2, figsize=(9, 7))
            for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flat):
              ax.scatter(Xdata_in[:, i], y_data_in)
              ax.set_xlabel(f"Xdata_in_col {i}")
              ax.set_ylabel('Target')
              ax.set_title(f"Xdata_in_col {i} vrs Target")
            plt.tight_layout()
            plt.show()
            #fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(9, 7))
            plt.figure(figsize=(4,5))
            plt.hist(y_data_in)
            plt.title('Target distribution')
            plt.show()
            plt.figure(figsize=(4,5))
            plt.hist(true_coefficients)
            plt.title('true_coefficients')
            plt.show()

        return X, y, true_coefficients

# Generating random dataset of size 1024x10 for X
Xdata_in, y_data_in, true_beta = rand_X_y_LR(nsamples=1000, nfeatures=10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an interesting problem.

I would calculate X, Y in the following way:

1. Generate a random vector Y
2. Generate a random vector of coefficients w
3. Generate a vector X_i for each desired feature using the expression:
   X_i = (Y - b) / w_i + noise
   with b being a random number, so that way X_i will have the size of Y
4. Combine the X_i to form an array with shape (num_samples, num_feauters)

In this way each feature X_i will have a linear relationship with Y. Each X_i has a high correlation with other X_i, but I consider that they are independent due to the noise that each one possess.

The code would look like this:

```
def rand_X_y_LR(nsamples=None, nfeatures=None, plot_XY = False):

        # Define the number of samples and features
        y = np.random.uniform(-200, 200, size=(nsamples))
        true_coefficients = np.random.uniform(-20, 20, size = (nsamples + 1))
        true_coefficients[-1] = 0
        # Generate a random design matrix X with values between 0 and 1
        X_list = []
        for i in range(nfeatures):
            b = np.random.uniform(-20, 20)
            X_temp = (y - b) / true_coefficients[i]
            noise = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=5, size = nsamples)
            X_temp += noise
            X_list.append(X_temp)
            true_coefficients[-1] += b
        X = np.vstack(X_list).T
        print(f"shape of random X; {X.shape}")
        ones_column = np.ones((len(X), 1))
        print(f"shape ones_column, {ones_column.shape}")
        X_plusOnes=np.hstack([ones_column, X])
        print(f"shape of X_plusOnes_column, {X_plusOnes.shape}")

        # Generate random coefficients for the features
        print(true_coefficients)
        print(f"shape of true_coefficients; {true_coefficients.shape}")

        # Generate random noise for the target variable
        noise = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1, size = len(X_plusOnes))
        #print("noise:", noise)
        y += noise

        # Calculate the target variable y using a linear combination of X and coefficients
        #y = np.dot(X_plusOnes, true_coefficients) + noise #X dot B
        print(f"y.shape; {y.shape}")

        if plot_XY == True:
            #plot each X column against target
            fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=round(num_features/2), ncols=2, figsize=(9, 7))
            for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flat):
              ax.scatter(Xdata_in[:, i], y_data_in)
              ax.set_xlabel(f"Xdata_in_col {i}")
              ax.set_ylabel('Target')
              ax.set_title(f"Xdata_in_col {i} vrs Target")
            plt.tight_layout()
            plt.show()
            #fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(9, 7))
            plt.figure(figsize=(4,5))
            plt.hist(y_data_in)
            plt.title('Target distribution')
            plt.show()
            plt.figure(figsize=(4,5))
            plt.hist(true_coefficients)
            plt.title('true_coefficients')
            plt.show()

        return X, y, true_coefficients
```

If we look at the distribution graphs with respect to each variable we will have something like this:

Taking into account row y, we see that there is a correlation with respect to the rest of X_i

[image]

If we look at a graph of the absolute correlations, we have the following:

[image]

It can be seen that in Y all are above 0.75.

Maybe when you use SGD you find other coefficients, it may be because a transformation is usually applied before using the algorithm.